# RIP Mira Furlan

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Mira Furlan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mira_Furlan), Croatian-American actress and singer, has just passed away at the age of 65. Her best-known screen role was as the Minbari ambassador in *Babylon 5*, a role that she played both boneheadedly and hairily, but always with care and compassion, through five seasons.

[image]

**R.I.P.**

Comment: Oh no, my condolences to her family, friends, and my fellow B5 fans.

Comment: She also had a fairly prominent recurring role on [Lost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danielle_Rousseau).

Comment: Very sad. Not that many of the B5 cast are left. Here's Delenn [at her best](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0g03huBl6g).

Comment: @IanThompson "Be somewhere else." No matter how many times I see that scene, chills every time. She was hardly ever a badass character, mostly being the voice of reason and compassion, so when she does go into threatening mode it's even more effective. Shows off Furlan's acting range too.

Comment: @Randal'Thor --- There was also 'You stand for nothing but your own petty interests' in the same episode. A charge that could fairly be placed against many politicians today!

Comment: @IanThompson The Minbari civil war arc never quite appealed to me as much as some of the other story arcs. I might rethink that after [hearing](https://www.facebook.com/officialjmspage/posts/252956932875916) that it (and some of Furlan's lines) were based on the Yugoslavian civil war that she experienced.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I also love the scene where she breaks the scepter and The Grey Council (as was prophecized).

Answer (score 7):

R.I.P. Mira, she's gone to the sea.

There's probably a good few members of this stack who best remember in the role of Delenn in Babylon 5. Looking her up at IMDB, her role as Delenn is the only program/film that I've ever watch with her in.